# How to reference columns with the same name in SQL?

Tags: sql

I wonder how can I reference second column in the GROUP BY clause if I have something like this:

```
select column1 as Title1,
       column2 as Title1
group by Title1
```

If I use "as", I understand I can not use GROUP BY column2 ? But I also can not use GROUP BY Title1 either?

Comment: You cannot give aliases in group by clause. You have to use column names in group  by clause because group by runs before select clause. BTW, which DBMS are you using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using column aliases in the `group by` is not supported by most databases -- it is not mandated by the standard.

You can *always* use the original column:

```
select column1 as Title1,
       column2 as Title1
from t
group by column2;
```

However, this should fail because you have no aggregation function on `column1`.  So, this is allowed:

```
select max(column1) as Title1,
       column2 as Title1
from t
group by column2;
```

If your database supports table aliases, it should also support positional arguments:

```
select max(column1) as Title1,
       column2 as Title1
from t
group by 2;
```